# holomorphic extension of forms 

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

hallo,

I have the following question: Let $M$ be a $n-$dimensional complex manifold and $X \subset M$ be a compact $n-$dimensional totally real analytic Riemannian submanifold. Let furthermore $\alpha$ be a 2-form on $X$. Is it possible to extend $\alpha$ to a holomorphic 2-form in a neighbourhood of $X$ in $M$? I hope for answers. Thanks in advance.

bruno

Comment: are there any references ?

Comment: does anyone have an idea ?


Comment: Wouldn't the existence of such an extension require $\alpha$ to be real-analytic on $X$?  

Comment: @bruno: what's a totally real submanifold?

Comment: @Andreas Blass: yes sure we assume that $\alpha$ is real-analytic.

Comment: @Sandor: http://planetmath.org/TotallyRealSubmanifold.html

Comment: can anyone give me some idea or some reference? I would be very thankfull.

Comment: When $\alpha$ is a function the answer is affirmative (the analytic expansion of $\alpha$ converges in a neighborhood of any point of X).

For $\alpha$ a form, locally extend it using local coordinates, and then observe that by uniqueness the extension is global.

Comment: yes but what about on the overlaps of two coordinate charts. do they agree on the overlaps? if yes, can you make a short sketch, please.

Answer (score 3):

Such extension exists. This follows from the followoing three facts.

1) For every point $x\in X$ there is a neighbourhood $U(x)\subset M$ and a holomorphic map 
$\phi: U(x)\to \mathbb C^n$  such that $\phi (U(x)\cap X)\subset \mathbb R^n$.

2) Let $\alpha$ be a real analytic two-form defined on $\mathbb R^n$, then it can be extended to a holomorphic two-form on a neighbourhood of $\mathbb R^n$ in $\mathbb C^n$ that retracts on $\mathbb R^n$

3) If you have two extensions of $\alpha$ to a same neighbourhoods of $\mathbb R^n$ then they coincide.

I don't know a reference for 1) but it should be something standard, to get 2) and 3) you can just use Taylor decomposition of $\alpha$.

Once you know 1,2,3 the statement follows easily.